# Мета инструменты для командной строки?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, makefile, метапрограммирование

Интересует какие есть программы для объединения работы других программ. Что-нибудь наподобие `Makefile`. Которые бы давали бы некие абстракции на верхнем уровне (правила, цели, источник, назначение, ...) и их можно было бы реализовывать путем написания последовательности конкретных утилит командной строки и других программ.

Нужно это для того, чтобы дать пользователю возможность выполнять команды не задумываясь о том как они будут выполняться под капотом.

А разработчику в тоже время, чтобы было проще разрабатывать их реализацию и при этом желательно кросплатформенно. Еще было бы здорово, чтобы внутри была встроенная проверка на то существует ли данная прога в системе и если нет, то утилита предлагала бы установить все необходимые зависимости.

Задумываюсь над тем, чтобы это реализовать в `nodejs`, но нода менее производительна и установленные зависимости для пакета, которые, как правило, съедают много места.

Пока меня устраивает `Makefile`, но вдруг есть что-нибудь более интересное. При запуске `Makefile`, если у юзера не будет нужных пакетов, то ему будет необходимо после каждого запуска устанавливать пакет на котором остановился `Makefile`. Да и с кроссплатформенностью не все так хорошо.

Comment: bash не пробовали? там прямо все есть. Или python.

Comment: Кросплатформенно - nodejs. Вот [статья](https://blog.sixeyed.com/docker-healthchecks-why-not-to-use-curl-or-iwr/), в ней освещена проблема с курлом, например. Makefile - тоже решение, использую сам, но оно очень специфичное, и много возни.

Comment: для описанного даже программа *make* не нужна: скопируйте те команды для языка оболочки, которые вы вставили в makefile, в отдельный файл, и запускайте его программой оболочкой, без посредника *make*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMake` попробуйте https://cmake.org/

> CMake is an open-source, cross-platform family of tools designed to
> build, test and package software.

Comment: слишком узкоспециализированное решение

Comment: @KoVadim шире Makefile

Comment: Makefile более кроссплатформенный.

Comment: @KoVadim `CMake` может генерировать Makefile-ы, а может проекты VS и другое

Comment: судя по вопросу, автору абсолютно не нужен студийный проект. Почитайте внимательно

Comment: Это больше инструмент для сборки. Мне нужна програ более общего назначения.

Comment: cmake - это не инструмент для сборки проекта. Это тула для генерирования разухабистых makefile, что бы другие люди смотрели на генеренку и говорили "не, make file - это ужас". Ну и ещё под другие системы сборки умеет.

Comment: @pank "Мне нужна програ более общего назначения" - эта програ называется *shell*.  Общее не бывает в принципе. Старая инженерная истина: чем более универсальный инструмент, тем менее удобно им работать. Сравниет ключ рожковый и ключ разводной. Так и здесь.

Comment: @kernel, по поводу «широты и узости». вот есть вопрос про [автоматизацию сборки scss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1144397/178576). я вот отлично представляю себе, как это сделать с помощью программы *make*. задача, вообще говоря, абсолютно элементарная. а что насчёт *cmake*? будет настолько же элементарно?